# Software to read DVDs recorded by a DVD recorder

Tags: dvd, file-format

I have a Sony RDR-HX925 that records video in various formats that trade space for quality (High Quality, Standard, Long play) etc.

I want to take programs I've taped off TV and put them onto my computer (and, eventually, my iPod). The first problem is that the computer doesn't even see anything on the DVD when its loaded.

Is there something like Exact Audio Copy for DVDs? Some other software that can read discs recorded by general public DVD recorder/players?

Comment: Hmmm, I am embarassed to admit it, but the reason why the PC was unable to read the DVD was in fact because it hadn't been finalised... I finalised it, and now it shows up perfectly in the Explorer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a [page on Videohelp.com](http://www.videohelp.com/dvdplayers/sony-rdr-hx925/7677) for this recorder.  It indicates some issues with homemade DVDs, and suggests that **copying the DVD to a DVD-RW disc** can overcome the issues.  There seems to be some media types that the player doesn't like, so using a different brand or speed of media may help.

It seems the errors that page shows have to do with attempting to play the discs in the player (or perhaps in another standalone DVD player).  The errors received were `player says either "No title" or "Disk format error"` ... if you see the same errors, you may be hitting the same issue.

If you recopy the DVD onto DVD-RW, your computer may be able to recognize the disc.  If so, you can copy the files on the DVD directly onto the hard drive for further processing.  DVDs use a UDF filesystem and a particular naming scheme for the files, and commercial DVDs add encryption to the data files.  I don't know if your recorder will add encryption to your homemade discs (I doubt it) -- if it doesn't, just copy the DVD contents into a new folder for an instant hard-drive backup of the DVD.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the link! I failed to find it in my searching.